# FTDI D2XX не те данные идут на отправку, как исправить?

Tags: java, android, микроконтроллеры, rs232

Использую библиотеку D2XX под Android - [тыц](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm)

Код взял этот - [тыц](https://github.com/ksksue/Android-FTDI-UART-Sample)

Создал еще одну кнопку и обработчик клика для отправки моей команды:

```
    public void OnClickTest(View v){
    if(ftDev == null) {
        return;
    }

    synchronized (ftDev) {
        if(ftDev.isOpen() == false) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onClickWrite : Device is not open");
            return;
        }

        ftDev.setLatencyTimer((byte) 16);
        byte[] send = new byte[]{1, 5, 0, 5, 0, 1, 28, 11};
        ftDev.write(send, send.length);
    }
}
```

По индикации вижу что команду я отправляю, но никакого ответа мне контролер не дает, по данной команде он должен включить 1 светодиод, такая же команда но с использованием другой библиотеки работает на ура.
В чем здесь подвох, что я не так сделал и как это исправить ?

Такое чувство что он что-то не то туда шлет

Comment: 1. Если аналогичную команду заслать через telnet результаты будут? 2. Я могу ошибатся, но java как-то особенно работает с байтами, подключите к пк 232 и посмотрите что приходят именно такие данные.

Comment: @JK_Action У меня есть USB to RS232 как можно через телнет послать команду на USB порт и получить ответ от контролера ?

Comment: Надеюсь правильно закоммутировать провода сможете? (Rx - Tx, Tx-Rx). В Win Используйте терминал типа [Terra Term](http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/) создайте файл с нужной вам последовательностью байт и закинуть это все в порт. В linux это что-то типо 

    cat binari_file > /dev/ttyUSB[num]